# Python: getting the created date of file inside gzip

Tags: python, gzip

I have a single XML file that has been compressed using gzip. I can open and read this file using the command:

```py
gzip.open("file.xml.gz", "rb")
```

Which gives me the data of the file. However, I also want to get the date and time that this file was created.

Is there a simple way in Python to get this metadata, that is the date and time the file inside the gzip was created, preferably without having to extract the file from the gzip? If not, what's the best code to extract the file and get this metadata from it?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was any metadata there. Is there?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yeah, there is. I'm able to extract the file manually and see the created date and time of the file on my machine, and it is definitely different to the date and time of the gzip file that encapsulates it.

Comment: Note that's likely not a "created" date, but a date of last modification...

Comment: @twalberg you are correct :) ... To extend on what I'm asking, here is a link to the file in question I am trying to ascertain. The gzip itself will have a creation/modified date equal to the date you download it. The XML file inside, however, has a creation/modified date equal to the date that file was created. It is that date I'm trying to get. https://www.nationstates.net/pages/regions.xml.gz (4MB in size)