# How to get the metadata of a file compressed in a gzip archive?

Tags: python, metadata, gzip

I have a very basic request.

All I need is to retreive the modification time of `my_text.txt` compressed in `my_archive.gz`.

[image]

```
from gzip import GzipFile

with GzipFile('my_archive.gz') as gzip_file:
    print(gzip_file.getinfo('my_text.txt').date_time)
```

This code is giving me this error : `AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'getinfo'`

When I try `print(gzip_file.mtime)`, I get `None`.

I expect this output : `(2023, 11, 13, 10, 9, 42)`

I'm so confused guys. Why Python can't retrieve this info while a tool like `7zip` can ?

Comment: I found a similar question but no answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463525/python-getting-the-created-date-of-file-inside-gzip

Comment: Does it work correctly if you first call `.peek(100)` (or any number >0) and then access `.mtime`?

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, I added a line `gzip_file.peek(100)` and when I printed `gzip_file.mtime`, I got `1699866582`. Then I converted it to get this  `datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 13, 10, 9, 42)`. Can you add that as an answer please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read between the lines in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile.mtime) of `.mtime`, you need to first call `.peek(n)` with some number of bytes for `n`. Otherwise, the decompression hasn't started at all, the underlying file hasn't been accessed and therefore no (meta-)information is available.